# Essential fatty acids function

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, diet

Why are essential fatty acids so essential? I know that if taken less then it would cause diseases, but what metabolic role do they play? Are their importance is just because of their structural role?

Comment: ''Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.''

Answer (score 2):

Essential fatty acids consist of two main EFAs - Omega 3 (Linoleic acid) and Omega 6 (Linolenic acid).

These two play vital roles in the following:

- Growth and development
- Brain functioning
- Skin health
- Hair growth
- Metabolism
- Reproductive system health
- Cell membrane integrity.

The fact that are bodies can't make them makes them very important in our diet. They are most important in our cell membranes.

Omega 3 is an amazing anti-flammatory. It does this by blocking the inflammation pathways in the cell.

We need more Omega 3 than 6 - about a ratio of 2:1.

[This is a pretty good page](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/why-you-need-essential-fatty-acids.htm) if you want more information.

Comment: thanks, but how do they achieve those functions?

Comment: @JM97 editing...